# What default value does initialisation with dynamic array assigns to its indexes?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, integer

My program requires the initial values in array to be `0`.

> I have to read an int from a file and then create array of that length

```
int array[no_read_from_file];
```

> However, to make sure they are initialised to `0` I am doing

```
int array[no_read_from_file]={0};
```

But since `no_read_from_file` doesn’t exist at compile time therefore error is encountered.

How can I achieve the desired behaviour without using any loops?

Also, what difference it will have if I use

```
int* ptr;
ptr=new int[no_read_from_file];
```

Are the initialised indexes defaults to `0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> ptr=new int[no_read_from_file];
> ```
>
> Are the initialised indexes defaults to 0?

No. That is default initialisation. Default initialised integers have an indeterminate value.

What you want to do is value initialisation. Value initialised integers have the value 0. Example:

```
ptr=new int[no_read_from_file]();
```

Better solution: Avoid memory leaks and other bugs from mishandled memory by using a RAII container:

```
std::vector<int> arr(no_read_from_file);
```

Comment: What does putting `()` after `ptr=new int[no_read_from_file];` exactly does?

Comment: @Ahmn21 That is syntax for value initialisation. It exactly changes the initialisation of the array elements to be value initialised instead of default initialised.

Comment: @Ahmn21 [Reputable documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) on the various types of initialization, what they mean , and how to use them.

Comment: @eerorika Do I have to add any `int` between `()` for the desired initialisation? What I mean is, If I write `(1)` .. would all the indexes have `value=1`?

Comment: @Ahmn21 No. You may not put anything between the parentheses when initialising an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [std::fill](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill)

```
#include <algorithm>

int* ptr;
ptr=new int[no_read_from_file];
std::fill(ptr, ptr + no_read_from_file, INIT_VALUE);
```

`INIT_VALUE` can be `0` or any other value that you want.